# How can i select whole folder with pictures in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a project in which i need to select whole folder with pictures inside it, and then do a transformation on all of the pictures inside the folder. Something similar like scripts in photoshop for massive pictures adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

Check PHP's [scandir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function

Loop through the results of your directory and do your image manipulation on each item.

Comment: I thought to do that, but the problem is selecting folder at first place. But thanks for advice!

Comment: I don't understand what you're having a problem with. Select the folder with `$files = scandir('path/to/my_images_folder')`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [CodeIgniters Manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html) does have some helper functions, but I'm not using them myself.

Personally, I'm more comfortable using the [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) PHP supplies you with. Combining this with [CodeIgniters Image Manipulation Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html) you can achieve some pretty nifty handling of your image processing:

```
$images = array("jpg", "png", "bmp"); // Just to make sure that we get image files

foreach(new DirectoryIterator("/path/to/images/") as $file)
{
    if( $file->isFile() && in_array($file->getExtension(), $images) )
    {
        $config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';
        $config['library_path'] = 'usr/bin/local/';
        $config['source_image'] = $file->getPathname();
        $config['new_image'] = $file->getPathname(); //Overwriting the source image
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']     = 75;
        $config['height']   = 50;       
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
        $this->image_lib->resize();
    }       
}
```

Or do some image processing of your own choice.

Comment: Thanks man. But i need to make a form, that allow other users to select folder with pics from their pc, something like input type="select" in html for files, i just need that for whole folder, if you get my point.

Comment: @Vladimir89 I get your point - but that has nothing to do with CodeIgniter or PHP. Thats a clientside issue, only solvable through some clientside scripting or clientside applets.

Comment: Yeah i thought the same, but i hoped that CI has some build in function for that. Anyway thanks man, you help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux, you can mass edit the images using ImageMagick's mogrify command.

Example: mogrify -resize 150x150 *.jpg
Result: all images were resized to 150x150

There is also a PHP class that deals with ImageMagick functionality in PEAR.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a function that could perform multiple image processing. But you could select files with glob() and then do your process in a loop ?

Comment: Well the point is that i need to make such a function, but first problem that i encounter was selecting folder with multiple files. And glob() function will select folder?

Comment: I don't know your file structure but glob('dir/*.jpg') would return all jpg files in "dir" as an array of filenames.